# Varíavel float com precisão de 2 dígitos após a vírgula em sql oracle

Tags: sql, float, oracle11g

Como faço para criar uma variável float com precisão de 2 dígitos após a virgula em uma tabela em SQL/Oracle.

Desde já, grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso você poderia usar o `decimal`, da seguinte maneira:

```
create table t (a decimal(10,2));
```

O primeiro número representa a precisão, que pode variar de 1-31, ele representa q quantidade total de dígitos que pode ter no número.

O segundo representa a escala, no caso a quantidade de dígitos que pode vim depois da virgula.